# Module parse failed: Unexpected character but file should be plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use [react-syntax-higligther](https://github.com/conorhastings/react-syntax-highlighter) in an application built with webpack.
When I import

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
```

app compile and runs fine, but if I try to do an import for the styles:

```
import arta  from 'react-syntax-highlighter/styles/hljs/arta';
```

the webpack compilation runs fine without errors, but when I try to run the application I have an error in the console:

> index.bundle.js:35943 Uncaught Error: Module build failed:
>   ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

I verified the imported file, and it is plain javascript, here below a portion:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.default = {
    "hljs": {
        "display": "block",
        "overflowX": "auto",
        "padding": "0.5em",
        "background": "#222",
        "color": "#aaa"
    },
    "hljs-subst": {
        "color": "#aaa"
    },
```

and furthermore usually these kind of errors arises during webpack compilation, this appear to be a message generated compile time and added to the generated code... I don't understand what is wrong.

**ADDITION**

Apparently the error is random, since I'm using `webpack --watch` to compile when file changes, if force recompile by exiting `webpack --watch` and running it again... it works! Any idea?

for completeness: webpack configuration here below:

```
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Constant with our paths
const paths = {
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 
};



// Webpack configuration
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.bundle.css'), 
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
      // Files will get handled by css loader and then passed to the extract text plugin
      // which will write it to the file we defined above
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      } ,
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }

    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],

  },
  watchOptions: {
  aggregateTimeout: 300,
  poll: 1000
}

};
```

Comment: What editor are you using? Most editors have an option to render whitespace, and it looks like your code might have some hidden characters (although this is just a theory). Also, I noticed that you have two spaces in your arta import, but I'm not sure this is what's causing the issue.

Comment: I would need some more information about your webpack configuration to help with that.

Comment: @TPorter updated the question...

Comment: as you got babel-loader do you have `.babelrc` file in your root directory ?

Comment: @Aaqib yes I have, and this appear randomly . since almost the time the compilation runs fine.